# Nuget package missing file Overlay.cs when using clickableTransparent Overlay with ImGui

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'ImGuiNET.RangePtrAccessor`1<ImGuiNET.ImDrawListPtr> ImGuiNET.ImDrawDataPtr.get_CmdListsRange()'.'
```

This is the error I'm getting and visual studio wants me to locate overlay.cs

```
using ImGuiNET;
using ClickableTransparentOverlay;
using System.Numerics;

namespace IMGUITEST
{
    
    public class Program : Overlay
    {
        bool checkBoxValue = false;
        int loveMeter = 0;
        string input = "";
        string input2 = "";
        protected override void Render()
        {
            ImGui.Begin("FirstWindow");
            ImGui.Text("Hello World!");
        }
        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting ImGui...");
            Program program = new Program();
            program.Start().Wait();

        }
    }
}
```

So I've been trying to create my first ImGui Window but I encounter this weird thing.
Up above is the code I am using and I have seen multiple examples of simular things working.
The Nuget packages i use are:
ClickableTransparentOverlay (This is the package missing overlay.cs)
`ImGui.NET`
`Sixlabors.imagesharp`
`Veldrid.ImGui`
`Vortice.Mathematics`
Also running .NET 6 and I've checked so all the packages are compatible with each other and .NET 6
I was expecting a simple window to open but it doesnt seem to work.
I have tried repairing visual studio and updating it also clearing the nuget cache and everything again in a new project.